# Get_template_part() problem with the_content()

Tags: loop, get-template-part

I am creating one page wordpress theme - i am new to wordpress dev.
The one page website have sections which represents pages. So every section on front page is page created via admin panel.

There is page.php and page-home.

Front-page needs to display all pages as a sections.

So I started with loop inside front-page.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

    $query = new WP_Query('pagename=home');
    if ( $query->have_posts () ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            get_template_part("page-home");

        endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();

 ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

First problem is: get_template_part not display the_content() from page-home.php, only displays html markup.

---

Here is the page-home.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
        <section id="first_section">
        <img class="jumbo wow bounceInDown animated" data-wow-delay="2s" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/jumbo-illustration.png" alt="Webdesigner and Developer" />
        <div class="tagline-wrapper wow bounceInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="2.5s">
        <!--  IF the_content() is placed here, it displays the content on front-page -->
        <h3 class="tagline"><?php the_content(); ?></h3>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <h3 class="tagline"><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php   else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?> 


    </section>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

Notice `<h3 class="tagline"><?php the_content(); ?></h3>`
Front page wont render the_content if is in the loop of , but if is before loop it displays normaly.

What I am missing?

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running a loop from secondary query in front-page.php and the loop from main in page-home.php. So, the post data in page-home.php won't be the data from the WP_Query in front-page.php.

Additionally, you are trygin to get full template files as template parts, which is not correct. I mean, front-page.php is a full template will header, content and footer and page-fome.php is also a full template with header, content and footer. You should re-think the logic to split template parts.

A basic (and silly) example to show you a correct approach:

**front-page.php:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

    $query = new WP_Query('pagename=home');
    if ( $query->have_posts () ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            get_template_part("content");

        endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();

 ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**page-home.php:**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
        <section id="first_section">
        <img class="jumbo wow bounceInDown animated" data-wow-delay="2s" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/jumbo-illustration.png" alt="Webdesigner and Developer" />
        <div class="tagline-wrapper wow bounceInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="2.5s">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        get_template_part("content");

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php   else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?> 


    </section>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**content.php:**

```
<h3 class="tagline"><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you @cybmeta! Yes, it is logic. I was created this `<pre><?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
    // 1 SECTION
    // HOME
 get_template_part('loop', 'home');


    // 2 SECTION
    // ABOUT
 get_template_part('loop', 'about');
 

    // 3 SECTION
    // SERVICES
 get_template_part('loop', 'services');
 

    // 4 SECTION
    // SKILL
 get_template_part('loop', 'skillset');
 

    // 5 SECTION
    // CONTACT
 get_template_part('loop', 'contact');
 ?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?></pre>`

Comment: Please, if this answer help you and answers your question, mark it as accepted answer so other users can find it easily.